# What is the relationship between Superman and Wonder Woman?

Tags: dc, superman, wonder-woman

What is the relationship between Superman and Wonder Woman?  Is it strictly professional or does Official Canon state that these two are now together?

Answer (score 5):

#### Superman and Wonder Woman would become romantically involved from issue #12 of "Justice League" (on sale August 29, 2012).

- Their relationship is consider canon since the New52 and has replaced the previous continuities pairing of Lois Lane as the primary love interest for Superman.

> **[Superman/Wonder Woman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superman/Wonder_Woman)** is an ongoing comic book series published by DC Comics that debuted in October 2013 as part of the company's The New 52 initiative. The series, written by Charles Soule with artwork by Tony Daniel, explores the relationship between Superman and Wonder Woman, two of DC Comics' most popular characters.

[image]

#### As for the much lamented Lois Lane:

In the New52 Superman #1, Lois Lane has gone from "G.B.S anchor and Pulitzer Prize winning reporter for The Daily Planet" to the "executive Producer of P.G.N.'s nightly news division" and the "executive Vice President of New Media." The issue portrays Lois behind the scenes, giving orders and running the show behind the camera. She gives the orders to cut a live feed from where the action is taking place because she does not want to endanger the lives of her reporters. Clark Kent and Lois work together, but their relationship isn't all that friendly.

[image]

As for her romantic entanglements, she is dating a man named [Jonathan Carroll](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Jonathan_Carroll_%28Prime_Earth%29). A man of dubious pedigree (in my opinion, she could do better). From the use of super-hearing in these last panels, it is implied there could have been more of a relationship potential but Lois found Clark's personal distance unable to be crossed. (Or maybe in this continuity she couldn't be bothered to try...)

[image]

[image]

Comment: It was a worst nightmare of all time..

Comment: What about poor old Lois?

Comment: @Richard What about poor old London?!?

Comment: I'm reminded of Brodie's idea about Superman having a kid in Mallrats.